# "Pattern-matching not exhaustive" and "this match case is unused" problem

Tags: ocaml

I am working on code for an assignment and in part of my code I run into problems regarding pattern matching in OCaml, and I can't figure it out.

```
    fun frag -> match make_and_parser t pf frag with
                | (Some children, suffix) -> match make_or_parser (pf h) pf suffix with
                                            | (None, left) -> (Some children, left)
                                            | (Some tree, left) -> (Some (children @ tree), left)
                | (None, suffix) -> match make_or_parser (pf h) pf suffix with
                                    | (None, left) -> (None, left)
                                    | (Some tree, left) -> (Some tree, left))
```

The error that I am getting is for this part

```
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(None, _)
File "make_parser.ml", line 42, characters 10-24:
Warning 11: this match case is unused.
val make_parser :
'a * ('a -> ('a, 'b) symbol list list) ->
'b list -> (('a, 'b) symbol list, 'b) parse_tree list option = <fun>
```

I was wondering if there is something obvious that I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parentheses. With your code, this is what OCaml sees:

```
fun frag ->
    match make_and_parser t pf frag with
    | (Some children, suffix) -> match make_or_parser (pf h) pf suffix with
                                 | (None, left) -> (Some children, left)
                                 | (Some tree, left) -> (Some (children @ tree), left)
                                 | (None, suffix) -> match make_or_parser (pf h) pf suffix with
                                                     | (None, left) -> (None, left)
                                                     | (Some tree, left) -> (Some tree, left))
```

From this, it is obvious that the first pattern match is non-exhaustive. It is missing the pattern for `(None, _)`. From this, it is also obvious that there is an unused match case in the second pattern match (i.e. `(None, suffix)`).

To fix your problem:

```
fun frag ->
    match make_and_parser t pf frag with
    | (Some children, suffix) -> (match make_or_parser (pf h) pf suffix with
                                 | (None, left) -> (Some children, left)
                                 | (Some tree, left) -> (Some (children @ tree), left))
    | (None, suffix) -> (match make_or_parser (pf h) pf suffix with
                        | (None, left) -> (None, left)
                        | (Some tree, left) -> (Some tree, left))
```

Notice the addition of extra parentheses around the pattern matches.

In conclusion, you were misled by your own indentation.